# Input a .i in a progress 10.2b

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I'm inputting a file that needs to be converted to an xml file but I also want to input a .i with the definition of the temp table used to create the xml. Also the delimiter isn't working (I need a way to convert a variable to something the command can read). Thanks!

```
define input  parameter pInputFile   as character no-undo.
define input  parameter pDelimiter   as character no-undo.
???define input  parameter pIncludeFile as character no-undo.???
define output parameter pOutputFile  as character no-undo init "/tmp/out..

/* start of .i */
define temp-table ttGeneric no-undo
  field cust_id  as integer
  field name     as character
  field address  as character
  field address2 as character
  field city     as character
  field state    as character
  field zip      as character
  field cust_key as character
index idx is primary cust_id.
/* end of .i */



input stream sImport from value(pInputFile) no-echo.
repeat:      
  create ttGeneric.
  import stream sImport delimiter pDelimiter ttGeneric.
 end.
input stream sImport close.

temp-table ttGeneric:write-xml("LONGCHAR", pOutputFile, yes).
```

maybe set a pre-processor in the calling program (some how).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delimiters to IMPORT and EXPORT must be literal strings.  You cannot use variables, fields, parameters or anything like that.

I have, on occasion, worked around that with a CASE statement.  i.e.:

```
case pDelimiter:
  when "," then import stream sImport delimiter "," ttGeneric.
  when "|" then import stream sImport delimiter "|" ttGeneric.
end.
```

Ugly.  But it works.

I think you might be trying to say that you want to pass the name of an include file that contains a TT definition?  And somehow associate that definition with a temp-table?

If that is more or less correct then you are probably being too specific about your requirement -- you probably really just want to dynamically create a TT whose definition is external to the program and unknown at compile time.

One way to do that is to use the read-xmlschema() method -- you're already using write-xml() so it's a small step...  first convert your .i to a little .p like so:

```
define temp-table ttGeneric no-undo
  field cust_id  as integer
  field name     as character
  field address  as character
  field address2 as character
  field city     as character
  field state    as character
  field zip      as character
  field cust_key as character
index idx is primary cust_id.

buffer ttGeneric:write-xmlschema( "file", "ttgeneric.xsd", true, ?, ?, ? ).

return.
```

(This little stub lets you create the .XSD file.  It serves no other purpose.  Just run it once to get that file.)

Then when you want to use that temp-table:

```
define variable tx as handle no-undo.

create temp-table tx.
tx:read-xmlschema( "ttgeneric.xsd", "file", ?, ?, ? ).
```

(Note:  Unlike with delimiters you can use variables & parameters etc. for the xsd name and it could be in a longchar rather than a file...)

The next adventure you will run into is figuring out a replacement for IMPORT that works with dynamic temp-tables.  Buffer handles don't have import() and export() methods :(

The following snippets may help:

```
define variable dummy as character no-undo extent 128.
...
dummy = ?.
import dummy.
...
do i = 1 to 128:
  if dummy[i] = ? then leave.
  tx:buffer-field( i ):buffer-value() = dummy[i].
end.
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot and gave me a better understanding of dynamic temp-tables.